# How to start multiple processes inside a linux service construct?

Tags: linux, bash, service, init.d

I am attempting to start multiple memcached processes from the linux service framework using the following logic:

```
RETVAL=0
pcount="$CACHES"
if [ ! -z "$pcount" ]; then
    while [ $pcount -gt 0 ];
    do
        (( pcount-- ))
        (( port=PORT + pcount ))
        daemon --pidfile ${pidfile}${pcount}.pid memcached -d -p $port -u $USER  -m $CACHESIZE -c $MAXCONN -P ${pidfile}${pcount}.pid $OPTIONS
        (( RETVAL=RETVAL + $? ))
    done
else
    daemon --pidfile ${pidfile}.pid memcached -d -p $PORT -u $USER  -m $CACHESIZE -c $MAXCONN -P ${pidfile}.pid $OPTIONS
    RETVAL=$?
fi
```

When run using the command `service memcached start`, it creates and updates pid files for each cycle in the loop, but only the last instance of the process remains running. That is, while each of the `/var/run/memcached/memcached(1 through 5).pid` are created and updated with a PID; those processes do not exist. `/var/run/memcached/memcached0.pid` is also created and updated and the PID points to a running process.

I turned on tracing and I can see that the loop is executed and the process invocation is made; however the process does not start (or likely, starts and immediately terminates so I dont see it as having started).

On the other hand, running this script directly as `/etc/init.d/memcached start` results in all the processes getting started correctly.

Can someone help me understand why the `service` framework is preventing the starting of the other instances except the last one?

Comment: The service command runs with a clean environment, do you have something particular in your environment variables ? If all else fails, run memcached with `strace -f` and redirect output to a file so you get a hint of why it terminates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @nos, I added strace -f to trace the calls during the `service memcached start` operation. I compared the traced calls between the unsuccessful/terminated process and the successful process. The only lines of significant difference that I found were:

```
< bind(26, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(11216), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
< dup(2)                                  = 27
< fcntl(27, F_GETFL)                      = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
< fstat(27, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 3), ...}) = 0
< ioctl(27, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fff20d5d780) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
< mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5dae958000
< lseek(27, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0
< write(27, "bind(): Permission denied\n", 26) = 26
< close(27)                               = 0
< munmap(0x7f5dae958000, 4096)            = 0
< close(26)                               = 0
< dup(2)                                  = 26
< fcntl(26, F_GETFL)                      = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
< fstat(26, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 3), ...}) = 0
< ioctl(26, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fff20d5d730) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
< mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5dae958000
< lseek(26, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0
< write(26, "failed to listen on TCP port 112"..., 54) = 54
< close(26)                               = 0
< munmap(0x7f5dae958000, 4096)            = 0
< exit_group(71)                          = ?
---
> bind(26, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(11211), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
> listen(26, 1024)                        = 0
> epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 26, {EPOLLIN, {u32=26, u64=26}}) = 0
> socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 27
> fcntl(27, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
> fcntl(27, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
> setsockopt(27, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, [1], 4) = 0
> setsockopt(27, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
> setsockopt(27, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
> setsockopt(27, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, {onoff=0, linger=0}, 8) = 0
> setsockopt(27, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
> bind(27, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(11211), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
> listen(27, 1024)                        = 0
> epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 27, {EPOLLIN, {u32=27, u64=27}}) = 0
> socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, 0)         = 28
> bind(28, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
> getsockname(28, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=31943, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
> gettimeofday({1393735036, 191154}, NULL) = 0
> sendto(28, "\24\0\0\0\26\0\1\3|\265\22S\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 20, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 20
> recvmsg(28, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"0\0\0\0\24\0\2\0|\265\22S\307|\0\0\2\10\200\376\1\0\0\0\10\0\1\0\177\0\0\1"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 108
> recvmsg(28, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"@\0\0\0\24\0\2\0|\265\22S\307|\0\0\n\200\200\376\1\0\0\0\24\0\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 128
> recvmsg(28, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\24\0\0\0\3\0\2\0|\265\22S\307|\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\24\0\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 20
> close(28)                               = 0
> socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 28
```

The top (<) one being from a terminated process and bottom one (>) from the last (successful) process. It is clear that the process is terminating due to lack of permission to bind to the port. On looking further, I realized that the SELinux was set to ENFORCE, which was preventing the memcached service from binding to port other than 11211 (the default port).

To the best of what I could figure, when I was running it without the `service` command, the behavior was simply that of a process (not a service) and hence the binding was not being enforced.

Turning off the ENFORCED mode of SELinux, got the `service memcached start` command working!